# How to handle modal bootstrap popup in Selenium2

Tags: javascript, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I was trying to handle modal popup but unable to handle, so that unable to perform any action on the page.

i have tried following below code:

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws InterruptedException {
    driver=new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("https://www.veritread.com/carrier/");
    //clicking on the any load then popup will be open
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//article[1]")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);

    String popup=driver.getWindowHandle();
    driver.switchTo().window(popup);
    //Trying to get text
    String str= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"modalPopContainer\"]/div/div/detail/section[3]/h1")).getText();

    System.out.println("Text of element: "+str);
}
```

Comment: did u tried fetching value directly without switching to popup?

Comment: Yes, I tried fetching value directly but unable to perform an action on the page.